# Without loss of generality, what may we validly assume?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

So I came across the question where it was asked:
Given that $a,b,c $ are positive integers, in a proof to the theorem $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$, we may assume without loss of generality that:

1. $a \geq c, b \geq c$
2. $a \geq b, a \geq c$
3. $a \geq b, b \geq c$
4. $a \geq c, c \geq b$

I deduced that the correct answer to the question would be (3) since those are the possible cases and if that's not true, we could reorder $a,b,c$ around. Is my idea of it correct?

Comment: We may assume *any of these* without loss of generality for this problem.  The third or fourth are the most convenient to assume (*there is no difference between them apart from labels*) as they provide the most structure that we could exploit to the relationships between the variables in order to make our eventual proof shorter with fewer cases to consider, but none of these would have been incorrect to assume while invoking the phrase "*without loss of generality*".

Comment: @jmoravitz It's not obvious to me why (3) or (4) would be valid since the RHS is not symmetric in $a,b,c$.  eg (3) would imply we have a term of the form (largest)^2 * (next largest) which would not be true in general.

Comment: It's only symmetric up to a cycle of $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz, even though, I had the same idea, turns out both 3 and 4 are wrong. Even I'm confused by this but which of 1 or 2 could be the answer?

Comment: Ah, yes, Jair observed correctly... had it been $a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2$ on the right, all would have been allowed.  I must have misread yesterday.  Still, the point remains that there doesn't have to be just one answer here.  Answer (1) is equivalent to saying "WLOG let c be the smallest" while answer (2) is equivalent to saying "WLOG let $a$ be the largest."  Either of these may be assumed (*one at a time*)...

Comment: The point of "WLOG" is again that if we were to break into cases and the proof of each case is identical apart from names, then we don't need to repeat the same argument again and can instead invoke the phrase "WLOG" in order to save time and space.  Here... continuing the proof where $a$ was the largest would have been done in the same way had we instead continued the proof where $b$ was the largest instead, and so on... noting that $a^3+b^3+c^3>a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$ can be rearranged to be $b^3+c^3+a^3>b^2c+c^2a+a^2b$

Comment: All the options are correct if the identity in question holds for every three positive integers $a, b, c$.

Comment: if $$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$$ holds for all triples $(a,b,c)$ of positive integers, then 
$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq b^2a + c^2b + a^2c$$ holds , too.

Comment: @miracle173: good observation. If an identity holds for all values of $a, b, c$ it must not depend on order of $a, b, c$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, but we don't know a priori that the inequality holds, this is in the context of trying to prove it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You are right. But I think if we want to prove the given identity, we cannot presume that it already holds for all integer.

Comment: Then we need to check for counter-example and not proof.

Comment: @JairTaylor: to avoid repetitions please check my comment to one answer posted here.

Comment: I have interpreted that this question is about "validity of proof technique which uses WLOG assumptions" . I am not doubting the result to be proved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing the comments above, the given relation is symmetric up to a cycle of $(a,b,c).$

1. Therefore, without loss of generality, the variable, say, $c$ may be
   validly assumed to be the smallest.

   [If we have a particular number at position 1, another particular
   number at position 2, and a third particular number at position 3, we
   can always cycle through $‘abc’\ldots‘bca’\ldots‘cab’$ until $c$'s position matches that of the smallest number.]

   So, option $(1)$ is correct.
2. Similarly, without loss of generality, the variable, say, $a$ may be
   validly assumed to be the biggest. So, option $(2)$ is also correct.
3. On the other hand, if our sequence of numbers is $(1,3,7),$ cycling
   through them will never result in them being in descending order. This contravenes option $(3),$ which thus is incorrect.

   [The [structure of the given relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4232990/without-loss-of-generality-what-can-we-assume/4232996?noredirect=1#comment8796744_4232996) does not give enough freedom for us to validly infer that if it results from the case whereby $a,b,c$ are ordered descendingly, then it automatically results from the remaining cases.]
4. Similarly, if our sequence of numbers is $(1,7,3),$ cycling through
   them will never sort them as specified in option $(4),$ which thus also is wrong.

Comment: I think all options are correct. We are supposed to prove an identity which holds for all positive integers $a, b, c$. Then we may rename the largest as $a$ and smallest as $c$ and the remaining as $b$ so that $a\geq b\geq c$ holds.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, the given theorem is indeed applicable for any three positive numbers since we can simply assign/label our numbers to suit. However, is the *proof* of the theorem valid if it argues that assuming that $a\geq b\geq c$ doesn't lose generality?

Comment: No it does not lead to a loss of generality because whatever be three numbers, I wish to call the largest as $a$, smallest as $c$ and the remaining as $b$.

Comment: Also whenever studying a proof involving "WLOG", one must spend a few minutes to see that the assumption does indeed preserve the generality.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, when encountering "WLOG", one ought to pause to understand why there is no loss of generality (if there indeed isn't).   Anyway, in my previous comment I was distinguishing between the application of the theorem and the proof of the theorem.

Comment: Let me reiterate that we are trying to prove a theorem about three numbers and what symbols we use to represent them is irrelevant to the theorem as well as the proof. And since numbers in the theorem can be ordered we can choose a specific ordering and then label accordingly.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The point is that a proof of "for all $a,b,c$ with $a \le b \le c$, the inequality $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$ holds" doesn't immediately lead to a proof of the general statement (with no ordering assumed on $a,b,c$). A proof of "for all $a,b,c$ with $a\le b$ and $a \le c$, the inequality $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq a^2b + b^2c + c^2a$ holds" does lead to a general proof.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I really don't get your point. Maybe I am overlooking something, but I don't see how the ordering affects the proof when the identity in question is not dependent on ordering of $a, b, c$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: given three numbers, if you can denote the minimum with $a$ then i don't see what prevents us to denote the maximum with another symbol $c$ and the remaining with $b$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The identity *does* depend on the order of $a,b,c$ in the following way: the right-hand side has an $a^2b$ term but not an $a^2c$ term, a $b^2c$ term but not a $b^2a$ term, and a $c^2a$ term but not a $c^2b$ term. So for instance taking $(a,b,c)$ to be $(1,2,3)$, $(2,3,1)$, or $(3,1,2)$ all give $23$ on the RHS; taking $(a,b,c)$ to be $(1,3,2)$, $(3,2,1)$, or $(2,1,3)$ all give $25$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: ok, we can assume $a$ to be the least because if not, we can do a cyclic permutation so that the least number comes first in the tuple $(a, b, c)$. Next we need to consider two cases separately : $b$ is maximum OR $c$ is maximum and the handling of these two cases can't be merged into one without any further analysis of the problem. I hope this is what you want to convey.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh If I may chime in: yes, exactly. This is essentially what I described in Points 1,3,4 of my answer.

Comment: +1 there. I think that I was swayed by the feeling that since the identity holds for all tuples $a, b, c$ the proof should not really be dependent on ordering.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. I agree that Misha's explanation was elucidating.